# Check if an address is an airport?

Tags: android, google-maps

If I use **Android Geocoder**

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(addressName, 3);
```

How can I check if an address is an **airport** (or not)? Because there is no such a method in **Address class**?

I would like something like

```
Address address = addresses[0];
address.isAirport();
```

Am I forced to use classis [Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and do the parsing and so on..? Because under **Address Component Types** I see an item

> airport indicates an airport.

Comment: Depending on what getFeatureName returns you may be able to do something like (pseudocode) if (address.getFeatureName().toLower().contains("airport"))

Comment: See the comment below. If there's guarantee that word "airport" will always be mentioned (if address is an airport) then that's the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Address.[getFeatureName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getFeatureName%28%29).  You'll have to look for the string "airport" yourself though.

Comment: I thought of that but I wasn't sure if the word "airport" will be always included in that parameter. If it would, then there's no problem...

Comment: You should be able to test this.  Just set the location of your emulator to the coordinates of various airports and see what values you get back.

Answer (score -1):

I have never used this, but if the functionality doesnt exist you need to create it.  There arent that many airports in the US.  Grabbing their geo coordinates, inserting them into a table, or array and looping through it would be really easy.

so if the address is in your list, then its an airport.

class adresss{

double array = {0.00,0.00,0.00}

loop through array
check if geocoordinate is in your array,
if it is return true;
}